# JSF 2 h:messages appears on the end of the form

Tags: validation, jsf-2

I have a screen which is implemented in JSF2 and I have validations on some of the fields, and when an error appears for a field that has no

```
<h:message for="fieldName" />
```

it always appear on the end of the screen with no style

I want to hide the messages summary even if I don't handle those validations

Comment: h:message or h:messages ?

Comment: We can't say anything without the code block.

Answer (score 1):

I guess they are just  warnings that you see when your project stage is set to `Development`.

In `web.xml` file, change:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and the messages disappear.

It is a feature of JSF 2 that shows you diagnostic messages when you are on `Development` stage. Actually you should changed that value in `web.xml` only when you want to put the project in production.